# Return content from function instead of echo

Tags: php

I have this recursive function:

```
    function displayTreeview($cats,$depth=0)
    {
        //if($depth==0){echo '<ul>';}
        foreach($cats as $cat)
        {
            $hasChildren=count($cat['children'])>0;
            $class = $hasChildren?' class="menu-item-has-children"':'';
            echo '<li'.$class.' data-children="'.count($cat['children']).'">'.$cat['name'];
            if($hasChildren){
             echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">';
             displayTreeview($cat['children'],$depth+1);echo '</ul>';}
             echo '</li>';
        }
        //if($depth==0){echo '</ul>';}
    }
```

How can I get all html code into a var and return it? I  tried with $var .= to append but did not succeded to get the correct code.

Comment: Do you still have the version with·appending to a variable? Because that's how you do it. At the begginig, create an empty variable, then, in each cycle, append the code to it, and then, after the cycle ends, you return it.

Comment: ^ couldn't have put it better.

Comment: Not working, it append only the first run of the function but when go recursive is not appending anymore.

Comment: @IonVasile correct, I didn't properly look at the code, however, this can easily be solved. Your function now returns something, even its recursive calls do, so just append what it returns. Got it? Where the recursive call occurs, you need to do `$variable .= displayTreeview(...);`

Comment: Only there? Or there and every echo? Cuz I already tried this ...

Comment: @IonVasile every echo, as well as the recursive call.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ukX6ke8g this is my new code but not working. The third param is $stringBuilder = '' . I paste it wrong in pastebin.

Comment: I will edit it and post an answer with explanation shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    function displayTreeview($cats,$depth=0, $stringBuilder)
    {
        $stringBuilder = '';
        //if($depth==0){echo '<ul>';}
        foreach($cats as $cat)
        {
            $hasChildren=count($cat['children'])>0;
            $class = $hasChildren?' class="menu-item-has-children"':'';
            $stringBuilder .= '<li'.$class.' data-children="'.count($cat['children']).'">'.$cat['name'];
            if($hasChildren){
                $stringBuilder .= '<ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">';
                $stringBuilder .= displayTreeview($cat['children'],$depth+1, $stringBuilder);
                $stringBuilder .= '</ul>';
            }
            $stringBuilder .= '</li>';
        }
        //if($depth==0){echo '</ul>';}

        return $stringBuilder;
    }
```

Notice the `$stringBuilder = '';` at the begining (before the commented condition). You need to have this here, and then append to it in the cycle. The way you had it, the variable got reset on every run of the cycle.

Comment: Since you're reinitializing `$stringBuilder` in the funciton, there's no point in passing it as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace every echo with a string append eg :

```
function displayTreeview($cats,$depth=0)
    {
        //if($depth==0){echo '<ul>';}
        $stringBuilder = "";
        foreach($cats as $cat)
        {
            $hasChildren=count($cat['children'])>0;
            $class = $hasChildren?' class="menu-item-has-children"':'';
            $stringBuilder .= '<li'.$class.' data-children="'.count($cat['children']).'">'.$cat['name'];
            if($hasChildren){$stringBuilder .='<ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">';displayTreeview($cat['children'],$depth+1);$stringBuilder .= '</ul>';}
            $stringBuilder .= '</li>';
        }
        //if($depth==0){echo '</ul>';}
        return $stringBuilder ;
    }
```

Comment: This code show me only one call of function, as you see the function is recursive.